# Updating BQ View SQL

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I can create a BQ view by calling client.create_table but I could not find a way to update the SQL of the view.

To create:

```
table = bigquery.Table(table_ref)
table.view_query = view_query
client.create_table(table)
```

To update? (does not work)

```
table = client.get_table(table_ref)
table.view_query = view_query
client.update_table(table, [])
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Are you tied to using this API? Or can you run a `CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW` statement instead?

Comment: I am tied to the API but I can run statements. CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW solves my problem, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second argument to `update_table` is a list of fields to update in the API. By passing an empty list you are saying: don't update anything. Instead, pass in `['view_query']` as the update properties list.

```
table = client.get_table(table_ref)
table.view_query = view_query
client.update_table(table, ['view_query'])
```

Or as Elliot suggested in the comments, you can use [DDL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/data-definition-language) to do this operation.

Answer (score 1):

I used CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW statement.

```
job = client.query('CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW `{}.{}.{}` AS {}'.format(client.project, dataset, view_name, view_query))
job.result()
```